# Facebook real-time updated application wall

Tags: facebook

I want to add real-time update wall in my facebook canvas application.
The posts of this wall must update automatically for every application user.
What is the best way to realize such application?

I have planned to use  with  in FBML page and periodic AJAX requests to the server (FBJS). When one user post something, this post will be returned to everybody by using these AJAX requests (format - JSON)

May be, there are a best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using it too on a night club website. The facebook request are client-side, so it doesn't give me performance problems to the server.

From X to X seconds, i make those calls to Facebook. What you can do is to don't update your content element (div for example) every time you make a call to Facebook. Instead, use an hidden field with the last comment id for example, and when you make the call to Facebook check if the last returned comment id is the same as your hidden field.