# How to get real-time status notification with Facebook SDK via listener

Tags: android, listener, facebook

I'm using Twitter4j and the Android Facebook SDK to fetch status messages. With Twitter4J I get real-time notifications whenever a new status has been added to the stream via `StatusListener` (Twitter4J). 
In the Facebook SDK I cannot find a similar way, I can only fetch entire streams over and over again in a fixed time interval using `RequestListener` (Facebook SDK) as far as I see it.

Is there any way to get notified of new statuses in realtime with the Facebook SDK in a similar way as with Twitter4J?

(Found a similar but unanswered question here: [Facebook real-time updated application wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231514/facebook-real-time-updated-application-wall))

Comment: Hi Mathias. I have a question related your Twitter 4j statement. Have you used a broadcast reciever to listen to status in Twitter? Could you please give me an example somehow. Thanks.

Comment: Hi SoH, sorry I don't remember, this project is already almost 2 years old. Can't really recall what I did back then. Haven't used the Twitter api ever since.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a realtime API

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime

but it's only for server-to-server communication, so it's not really useful if all you have is a mobile app without a server infrastructure that your app can subscribed to - which is what I was looking for in my particular case.

See the Q&A at http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=56610